# Cant' use my applet because of No applet found error

Tags: java, applet

I am writing a program for a class where I need to have the american flag scale the flag pole to the national anthem. I have the code but get an error that the applet is not found even though its there. I am using eclipse. Can anyone help me with what I am missing?

Thanks in advance...

Code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Lab5b extends JApplet {
  private AudioClip audioClip;

  public Lab5b() {
    add(new ImagePanel());

    URL urlForAudio = getClass().getResource("audio/us.mid");
    audioClip = Applet.newAudioClip(urlForAudio);
    audioClip.loop();
  }

  public void start() {
    if (audioClip != null) audioClip.loop();
  }

  public void stop() {
    if (audioClip != null) audioClip.stop();
  }

  /** Main method */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Create a frame
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Lab 5");

    // Create an instance of the applet
    Lab5b applet = new Lab5b();
    applet.init();

    // Add the applet instance to the frame
    frame.add(applet, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    // Display the frame
    frame.setSize(200, 660);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
  private ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon("image/us.gif");
  private Image image = imageIcon.getImage();
  private int y = 550;

  public ImagePanel() {
        Timer timer = new Timer(120, new TimerListener());
        timer.start();
    }

    class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            increaseY();
        }
    }


  public void increaseY() {
        if (y > 0) {
            y--;
            repaint();
        }
    }

  /** Draw image on the panel */
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    if (image != null) {
      g.fillRect(0, 0, 10, 660);
      g.drawImage(image, 11, y, 160, 84, this);
        }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things to note

- `Applets` do not begin execution at `main()` method. However, it is
  possible to execute the `applets` by using the Java interpreter (by
  using the `main()` method) if you extend your `class` with `Frame`.
- It is important to have the `init()` method since it is called by the
  browser or applet viewer to inform this applet that it has been
  loaded into the system. It is always called before the first time
  that the start method is called.
- `JFrame` and `JApplet` are all top level containers and instead of
  adding the `applet` to the `frame`, i would rather create an object
  of `JPanel` since it can be added to both `JFrame`/`JApplet`. In your
  case just add `ImagePanel` to either of the top level container.
- I/O Streams do not provide much scope for `applets`.
- It is not possible for an `applet` to access the files on the users
  hard disk.

Read more [here](http://www.developer.com/open/article.php/791151/Java-Applet-Basics.htm)

Comment: *"It is not possible for an applet to access the files on the users hard disk."*  Yes it is possible. There are two ways (short of security bugs in the JRE).